# Migrating from Gmail to Google Apps

Tags: email, migration, g-suite, gmail

Our company is trying to migrate our email from Gmail to its Google Apps account.
We upgraded to the Premiere Edition in order to get access to the advanced tools for email migration.
We are hoping to preserve and import the labels, filters and contacts as well.
Is this possible?
Can someone direct me to a solution?

Thank you!

--- Edit to Question below ---

Here is the issue. I have tried using the "Migrate mail from mail server". 
The first part of the process required me to "Establish server connection"

I set the values in this section to the following:

1. Name this server connection: Gmail
2. Type: IMAP (By default)
3. Server software: Other
4. Security: SSL
5. Port: 993
6. IMAP Path Prefix: (left blank)
7. User mail filters: (left unchecked)
8. Spam checks: (left unchecked)
9. Allow up to: 5 connections.

When I try to go to the next step,I get the following error: "We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for taking the time to try and resolve my issue.
I finally had Google Support look into the issue.

They had to change a couple of settings in order for the Migration to start working again.

1. They changed the host to : imap.googlemail.com (instead of imap.gmail.com)
2. They dropped the number of connection to 3 (insetad of 5)

Once again, I really appreciate everyone's feedback on this.

Answer (score 2):

Premiere Edition accounts comes with an Email Migration tool that does just what you asked for (but don't use the POP3 protocol because it won't preserve your labels).

It won't migrate your contacts though, to do that you need to export them for your current account, then import them in your new Google App account.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've got a premier account you should be able to just use imap to connect to the gmail servers from the email migration tool.  This should preserve the labels since they're just stored as imap folders (double check this first though).  It won't migrate the contacts or filters though, that'll need doing manually, I don't believe anybody has created anything to automate doing that for you.

See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/11220/gmail-google-apps-to-gmail-migration)

Comment: Here is the issue. I have tried using the "Migrate mail from mail server". The first part of the process required me to "Establish server connection"
I set the values in this section to the following:
1. Name this server connection: Gmail
2. Type: IMAP (By default)
3. Server software: Other
4. Security: SSL
5. Port: 993
6. IMAP Path Prefix: (left blank)
7. User mail filters: (left unchecked)
8. Spam checks: (left unchecked)
9. Allow up to: 5 connections.
When I try to go to the next step,I get the following error:

"We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later."

Answer (score 0):

First, you won't be able to transfer contacts and filters this way. It's fairly easy to get contacts across though (just export/import). As far as I know, there is no way to export filters (neither from the UI or from the API).

If you are having trouble using the IMAP tool, you can always use other IMAP migration tools, such as [Yippiemove](http://www.yippiemove.com). Moreover, you won't need to upgrade Premier to use these tools, as they work well with Google Apps Standard too.

Comment: Yippie move seemed like it would have worked. However my company did not want to use a third party solution. Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We have coded a tool that takes care of email migration:

http://improffice.com/emailtransfer